# AMSlideMenu back button not showing on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, amslidemenu

I've inherited an iOS application which is built around the
[AMSlideMenu](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu) CocoaPod.  The view controller navigation works fine on
iOS 8.4 showing a back button with the title of the previous view
controller in the pushed view controller but on iOS 9.0 the back
button is not showing any more.  I've opened and [issue](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu/issues/165) on Github for
it but I've got no reaction so far from the developer.  Is it a known
problem?  What has changed in iOS 9 that this CocoaPod stopped working
properly?  Are there any workarounds or does somebody has any idea how
to debug and fix it?

Comment: is it possible for you to rewrite the code with new side menus like mfsidemenu or swreveal or refrost etc.. Amslidemenu have problems

Comment: Is AMSlideMenu an abandoned project?

Comment: no ... but there are some problems.. I prefer MFSideMenu

Comment: @TheDude Did you get a solution